# how would I optimize this wordpress query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure out the optimal combination of indexes for the query below. Right now its Using temporary; Using filesort and killing my vps. Queries take from 6-10 seconds.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  wp_posts.ID     
FROM 
  wp_posts
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
  INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id) 
WHERE
  1=1
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
  AND wp_terms.slug IN ('pie') 
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY 
  wp_posts.ID     
ORDER BY 
  wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: mind to include your execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this compare, performance-wise?

```
SELECT
  p.ID
FROM 
  wp_posts AS p
WHERE
  1=1
  AND p.post_type = 'post'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM wp_term_relationships AS r 
           INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS t ON 
             r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id AND t.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
           INNER JOIN wp_terms AS m ON 
             m.term_id = t.term_id AND m.slug IN ('pie') 
     WHERE r.object_id = wp_posts.ID 
  )
ORDER BY 
  p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Indexes should be on all the primary and foreign keys, on `wp_terms.slug`, on `wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy` and a composite one over `wp_posts.post_status, post_type, post_date`.

Comment: i added a composite index but the query didn't use it. It stuck with the index on the primary key. Unfortunately I can't really change the structure of the query due to wordpress's nature but I appreciate the help.

Comment: for some reason the index you mentioned slows down the entire query. Mysql seems to change the join order of the tables with execution time atleast 4x longer. I'm not sure why even though explain extended shows that the index isn't being used.

Comment: @Incognito: Ok, it was just a try. To track down where all the time goes, execute the query incrementally. First, just `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ...`, then add the JOINs one by one. Maybe this helps spotting the issue.